# Is there another way to go about getting the appropriate sdk tools for my genymotion

Tags: android, sdk, adb, genymotion

Whenever I put the SDK path in the ADB section of my genymotion, I get the error message that this folder does not contain any android SDK tools. But this is the same path used by my android studio
Kenny/AppData/local/Android/SDK.  Help please.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the genymotion.log file (located in `~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log`), you should be able to understand what Genymotion is missing. The most common issue is that it cannot find either the `adb` or the `aapt` binaries.

If this is the case you can install them from Android Studio: open the SDK Manager, then search for "platform tools" (for `adb`) and "build tools" (for `aapt`).